# SQL Server select from linked server throw error if user has "deny view definition"

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have users with datareader permission on my sql, the problem is that i noticed that the users are doing "fishing" query a lot (they don't know what exactly should be querying to get what thy need).

This is a production SQL and we started to have deadlock because of those users.
Trying to don't break their process i applied "deny view definition to [user]" so they cannot see the list of tables, view, stored procedure, so no more "fishing"

This was a great solution, it works perfect if you connect directly to the SQL Server, you can run queries (select) but you cannot see the list of tables.

However many users are using those account to connect to our SQL using linked server, and when the run a query using the linked server they are getting error:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM [SERVERSQL].[DATABASE].dbo.[TABLE]
```

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVERSQL" does not contain the table ""[DATABASE]"."dbo"."[TABLE]"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Using SQL Server version 2014 (v12.0.2000.8) and 2016 (v13.0.5492.2).

What is the correct way to hide tables, view, stored procedures, etc but allow select and make it work on linked server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linked server from one SQL Server to Another:
`Linked server name is: PLWNSAVSQL02D` which is SQL Server

This sql to linked server works:

```
select count(*) from [PLWNSAVSQL02D].[SFI_WMS].dbo.[TCOMPANYPALLETMESSAGES];
```